# Where can I find my Dropbox public folder URL?

Tags: dropbox

I want to share my public Dropbox folder, but I can't seem to find what it's URL is.

So where can I find it?

Comment: [This help page](https://www.dropbox.com/help/16/en) might help you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think you can actually share the **Public folder**, just files inside it.

Drop a file into the folder, right click it → *Dropbox* → *Copy Public Link*.

If you have delete the public folder by mistaken then **create new** one and that's all.

---

*One more time*: *Files must be in the **public** folder for you to share a url*

---

[image]

You probably want to look at shared folders;

https://www.dropbox.com/help/19

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was what I found out too, when I looked at their help. Can you add this image into your answer: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1656836/win/copy-public-link.png?

Comment: Image added, glad you found a solution.

Comment: 'copy public link' doesn't show on my dropbox. what happen?

Comment: Yeah copy public link doesn't show on mine either... anyone know if this needs to be activated first? Thanks.

Comment: @dan files must be in the public folder.

Comment: This feature is gone for new users.

Answer (score 2):

You actually can, when you're logged in on https://www.dropbox.com/home/Public click on the `Share link` button, there you'll be taken to a url like:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/<some random looking string>
```

Which will be the accessible to anybody, and you can share it from there via email/facebook/twitter/etc or just copy the url. There, you'll see the contents of your public folder (files and subfolders)